# How to fix Windows Backup Error Code 0x8078015B

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I'm trying to setup Windows Backup to backup my laptop to a network attached storage drive. The backup runs for about an hour an then fails giving error code 0x8078015B.

When I checked the windows error log I find the entry I've listed bellow. Any one any idea how to resolve this? If I have to disable services one by one it could take me weeks to figure out what is causing the issue.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Date:          15/10/2010 22:13:50
Event ID:      517
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      Laptop
Description:
The backup operation that started at '‎2010‎-‎10‎-‎15T18:06:13.550844800Z' has failed with following error code '2155348315' (Windows Backup encountered an error when accessing the remote shared folder.). Please review the event details for a solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is resolved.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Backup" Guid="{1DB28F2E-8F80-4027-8C5A-A11F7F10F62D}" />
    <EventID>517</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-10-15T21:13:50.478235300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>121885</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="7968" ThreadID="5460" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Laptop</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BackupTime">2010-10-15T18:06:13.550844800Z</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">2155348315</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorMessage">%%2155348315</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you backing up any remote shares?

This "[0x8078015B - Error when accessing the remote shared folder](http://web.archive.org/web/20101020090400/http://www.kconnolly.net:80/Blog.aspx?Page=1) [archive.org]" seems to be the only thing I can find with that error code along with a solution.

> If you're getting the errors below while doing a backup in Windows 7, just delete or move your old backup. For some reason, to do a 500+ GB backup, it needs 500 GB free in addition to the space it's about to delete from the previous system image. I guess they do it by creating the full backup first and then deleting the old one. So if you want to keep 500GB backed up, you'll need 1TB of space (plus the normal 10% margin for error, so 1.1TB).
>
> And of course Windows won't let you choose to include a system image of only one drive... grrr, the one Windows is on is the only one that needs an image; the rest is backed up elsewise... but whatever. Just wipe your old one and it'll finish fine.

Hope it's of some use.

Comment: +1 I love it when people use my sites for reference!  Hope the solution (delete your old backup before backing up) solves the problem.

Comment: Down voting because the link is dead now and the answer here does not include any useful information other than the link.

Comment: The link is dead, but the solution offered is *delete (or move/archive) your old backup before creating the new one*.  Something must have gone wrong when Windows was trying to update the previous system image in-place.

Comment: @Steven I edited his answer to fix the deadlink, and included a quote from it.

Comment: @tsilb, what happened to your site? Are the articles still online somewhere? :)

Comment: @mwfearnley Sadly, no.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem, but found the answer today.
Go manual, pick the harddrive you want to save on, then when you reach the list of the file with the checkbox, outside the the central square of the window there's another checkbox.
Uncheck it and it should work, that's what it did for me.

Comment: He means the "Include a system image of drives: [list of system drives]" option

Comment: This doesn't help if you actually *want* it to create a system image...  That's the whole point of the backup for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error while trying to use Windows Backup (Windows 7 Backup) on Windows 10 Home. My backup job was supposed to backup tp a Seagate PersonalCloud NAS decice. The error said Windows Backup could not access the destination location, even though Windows Backup let me choose the location as a compatible place to backup.
Turns out the issue is that Windows 10 thought the wireless network I was connected to was a Public network, when I was actually connected to my home (Private) network...for whatever reason.

So here's how to tell Windows it's ok to allow sharing and accessing shared folders, printers, etc on your Private network.

1. Open the ALL SETTINGS, either by clicking it in the Action Center icon (bottom right corner of screen) or by right-clicking the Windows Start button (bottom left corner).
2. Click NETWORK AND INTERNET.
3. Click WIFI on left side of screen.
4. Click the name of the network you are connected to, right below the slide switch that allows you to turn WiFi on and off (just above Show Available Networks). This shows the properties of the network you are connected to.
5. Right below where it says MAKE THIS DEVICE DISCOVERABLE, slide the switch to ON position.
   That's it! This will make it possible to access shares on other computers, and make it possible for other computers to access shared folders, printers, etc on your computer that you have shared and made available.

Worked on 3 Windows 10 computers for me.
NOTE: If you connect to a different WiFi network you may have to repeat these steps for each different wireless network you connect to. Be mindful that you probably would not want to do this on an actual Public network, such as a store or restaurant because people you don't know are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error a few times; it was not easy to reproduce. A few things I changed (which seemed to help):

- I stopped working on my computer during backups (I suspect that removing files at the moment Windows is trying to back them up could result in this error?).
- I plugged in **both** USB ports on my Seagate Fast HDD portable drive (the destination for the backups), as I'm not certain one port was able to supply ample power during the entire backup. [See more about this here](https://superuser.com/questions/70662/why-does-my-usb-cable-have-an-extra-red-plug).

Answer (score 0):

Delete old backups before starting a new one. That fixed it for me. Destination was local network shared folder, I just deleted everything inside from last backups. Space was not the issue, there was more than enough.

Comment: This is the solution behind the dead link from the currently highest raked solution... therefore, it's worthwhile, even if there is no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error even after removing a mapped drive and any shares to my NAS. Doing a chkdisk -r on the laptop solved it. There were two bad clusters in the systems directory. Yeah, nothing to do with remote anything, great error reporting. I have also read that the backup location needs to have twice the capacity of the backup image. Now to install the SSD, which was the swamp I am trying to drain.